# Create a download multipage pdf from html using .print()

Tags: pdfhtml

I'm creating some books by some datas taked with a json, I created a html page to set the print layout but i need to export it, but not by the printer panel I already created a second page (printPdfBook.html) like for the print html file (printBook.html), with the same settings. I tryed some libraries like jsPDF, html2canvas, but when I click on the download button the css setting are lost or I have to create a separated setting for each books and I can't.
I wrote i would use .print() but any useful idea is welcome.
Can someone help me?
Advance thanks to all.
Attached the table structure i used for the print html file.

```
<section id="bookCover" class="sheet">
        <table class="coverPage">
                <thead class="coverHead">
                    <tr class="coverLogoSpace">
                        <th class="coverLogo">
                            <img class="coverLogoImg" src="/padova/img/logo2.png"/>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody class="coverBody">
                <tr class="coverBodyTitle">
                    <th class="coverTitle">
                        {{mod.name}}
                    </th>
                    <th class="coverBookTitle">
                        {{title}}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr class="featuresCol">
                    {{#with mod}}
                    {{#each features}}
                        {{#if value}}
                            <td class="featureNameSpace">{{name}}</td>
                        {{/if}}
                    {{/each}}
                    {{/with}}
                </tr>
                <tr class="featureNamesCol">
                    {{#with mod}}
                    {{#each features}}
                        {{#if value}}
                            <td class="featureValueSpace">{{value}}</td>
                        {{/if}}
                    {{/each}}
                    {{/with}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="footerInfo"></td>
                  </tr>   
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </section>

    {{#each pages}}
            
    <section class="sheet">
        
        <table class="snglImgTable">
            <tbody class="snglImgBody">
                <tr class="snglImgCol">
                    {{#with picture}}
                        <th class="snglImg{{ifW w h}}">
                            <img class="snglImgDetail {{ifW w h}}" src="{{url}}"/>
                        </th>
                    {{/with}}
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
                
    {{/each}}

    </section>
```

```
    #buffering{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.bufferingGif{
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: calc(50% - 25px);
    margin-right: calc(50% - 25px);
    margin-top: 350px;
}
.bufferingText{
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: calc(50% - 125px);
    margin-right: calc(50% - 125px);
    font-size: 1em;
    color: rgb(80,80,80);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;
}
#contentItem{
    opacity: 0;
}
@media print{
    html{
        width: 210mm;
        margin:0mm;
        padding: 0mm;
    }
    body{
        width: 210mm;
        padding: 0mm;
        margin: 0mm;
    }
    #buffering{
        display: none;
    }
    #contentItem {
        opacity: 1;
        width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;
        margin: 0mm;
        padding: 0mm;
    }
    table{
        width: 210mm;
        padding: 0mm;
        margin: 0mm;
    }
    .coverPage{
        width: 210mm;
        padding: 0mm;
        margin: 0mm;
    }
    .coverHead{
        width:210mm;
        margin:0mm;
        padding:0mm;
    }
    .coverLogoSpace{
        width:210mm;
        margin:0mm;
        padding:0mm;
    }
    .coverLogo{
        display: block;
        width: 50mm;
        margin-right:80mm;
        margin-left:80mm;
        margin-top: 30mm;
    }
    .coverLogoImg{
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0mm;
        padding: 0mm;
    }
    /*body cover*/
    .coverBody{
        width:210mm;
        margin:0mm;
        padding:0mm;
    }
    .coverBodyTitle{
        display: block;
        width:100mm;
        margin-left: 55mm;
        margin.right: 55mm;
        margin-top: 80mm;
    }
    .coverTitle{
        display: block;
        font-size: 30pt;
        font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color:black;
        font-weight: normal;
        opacity: 0.8;
        border-bottom: 0.5mm solid black;
    }
    .coverBookTitle{
        display: block;
        font-size: 12pt;
        font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color:black;
        font-weight: normal;
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
    .featuresCol{
        display: block;
        width: 140mm;
        padding: 0mm;
        margin-right: 35mm;
        margin-left: 35mm;
        margin-bottom: 0mm;
        margin-top: 120mm;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .featureNamesCol{
        display: block;
        width: 140mm;
        padding: 0mm;
        margin-right: 35mm;
        margin-left: 35mm;
        margin-bottom: 0mm;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .featureNameSpace{
        width:20mm;
        margin:0mm;
        padding:0mm;
        font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;
        font-size: 10pt;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
    .featureValueSpace{
        width:20mm;
        margin:0mm;
        padding:0mm;
        font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;
        font-size: 10pt;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
    .footerInfo{
        display: block;
        width:190mm;
        margin-left:10mm;
        margin-right:10mm;
        margin-bottom: 10mm;
        font-size: 8pt;
        color: black;
        opacity: 0.6;
        margin-top: 3mm;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    /* pagine book */
    .snglImgTable{
        width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;
        margin:0mm;
        padding:0mm;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .snglImgBody{
        width: 200mm;
        height: 287mm;
        margin:5mm;
        padding:0mm;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .snglImgCol{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin:0mm;
        padding:0mm;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .snglImgverticalBasedImg{
        height: 287mm;
        width:200mm;
        margin: 0mm;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .snglImghorizzontalBasedImg{
        width: 200mm;
        height: 141mm;
        margin: 0mm;
        margin-top: 78mm;
        margin-bottom:78mm;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: block;
    }
    .snglImgsquareBasedImg{
        width: 200mm;
        height: 200mm;
        margin: 0mm;
        margin-top: 48.5mm;
        margin-bottom:48.5mm;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: block;
    }
    .verticalBasedImg{
        width: 200mm;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: block;
        display: table-cell;
    }
    img.verticalBasedImg{
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .horizzontalBasedImg{
        width:200mm;
        height: auto;        
    }
    .squareBasedImg{
        width:200mm;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```